# Selecting GROUP BY records condensed from two or more table records

Tags: sql, rdbms

I have two simple tables:

`HospitalEpisode:`

```
|ID|DateAdmit|DateDischarge|
```

and

`Unit Episode:`

```
|ID|HospitalEpisodeID|DateAdmit|DateDischarge|
```

One hospital episode can have multiple Unit episodes.

I need to generate a report of all patients who had two or more unit episodes.  This is how I started

```
SELECT * from HospitalEpisode
INNER JOIN UnitEpisode
ON HospitalEpisode.ID=UnitEpisode.HospitalEpisodeID
GROUP BY HospitalEpisode.ID
```

This of course does not count unit episodes within a group, does not filter for those where the UnitEpisodes are two or more and does not allow me to step through each unit episode within a hospital episode in order to extract the relevant data.  Even if I could get a list of HospitalEpisodes with two or more UnitEpisodes I could then run a second query to pull the specific data for the report.  Any assistance appreciated!

Comment: Please tag RDBMS. You should have seen [a pop up](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274634/73226) already reminding you of this when asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USE `HAVING` clause to get all hospital episodes with 2 or more unit episodes.

```
SELECT UE.HospitalEpisodeID from HospitalEpisode HE
INNER JOIN UnitEpisode UE
ON HE.ID=UE.HospitalEpisodeID
GROUP BY UE.HospitalEpisodeID
HAVING COUNT(*) >=2
```

if you want unit episode details matching above criteria, you need to run above select in sub query

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT UE.HospitalEpisodeID from HospitalEpisode HE
    INNER JOIN UnitEpisode UE
    ON HE.ID=UE.HospitalEpisodeID
    GROUP BY UE.HospitalEpisodeID
    HAVING COUNT(*) >=2
)T
JOIN UnitEpisode UE 
on T.HospitalEpisodeID = UE.HospitalEpisodeID
```

Comment: Thank you - this is a real help!

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
SELECT * from HospitalEpisode
LEFT JOIN UnitEpisode
ON HospitalEpisode.ID=UnitEpisode.HospitalEpisodeID
GROUP BY HospitalEpisode.ID
```

Comment: Copied the question and pasted it as answer!!

Comment: Will this code work.. HospitalEpisode has 3 columns and unit episode column has 5 column and u are selecting all the columns in select list and do u think group by HospitalEpisode.ID alone will work!!!

Comment: No, because I actually wanted to test for >= 2 admissions in Unit